# stdout can print correct result but not output in ruby although i have return the values

Tags: ruby, algorithm

```
def two_sum(nums, target)
    for i in 0..3 - 1
        for j in 0..3 - 1
            if nums[i] + nums[j] == target && i < j && i != j
                puts '[' + (i - 1).to_s + ',' + (j - 1).to_s + ']'
            end
        end
    end
    return (i - 1), (j - 1)
end

def main()
    nums = Array.new()
    target = gets().to_i
    nums = gets().to_i
    two_sum(nums, target)
end

main()
```

The requirement of the exercise is to print out numbers whose sum is equal to a target number. You need to get an array of integers and the target number at first.

Can anyone debug it for me? Thank you.

[image: output has nothing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will leave it others to debug your code. Instead I would like to suggest another way that calculation could be made relatively efficiently.

```
def two_sum(nums, target)
  h = nums.each_with_index.with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |(n,i),h|
    h[n] << i
  end
  n,i = nums.each_with_index.find { |n,_i| h.key?(target-n) }
  return nil if n.nil?
  indices = h[target-n]
  return [i,indices.first] unless n == target/2
  return nil if indices.size == 1      
  [i, indices.find { |j| j !=i }]
end
```

​

```
two_sum([2,7,11,15], 9)           #=> [0, 1]
two_sum([2,7,11,15], 10)          #=> nil
two_sum([2,7,11,15], 4)           #=> nil
two_sum([2,7,11,2,15], 4)         #=> [0, 3]
two_sum([2,11,7,11,2,15,11], 22)  #=> [1, 3]
```

In the last example

```
h #=> {2=>[0, 4], 11=>[1, 3, 6], 7=>[2], 15=>[5]}
```

---

Note that key lookups in hashes are very fast, specifically, the execution of the line

```
indices = h[target-n]
```

---

Building `h` has a computational complexity of O(`n`), where `n = num.size` and the remainder is very close to O(`n`) ("very close" because key lookups are close to constant-time), the overall computational complexity is close to O(`n`), whereas a brute-force approach considering each pair of values in `num` is O(n^2).

---

If a hash is defined

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
```

executing `h[k]` when `h` has no key `k` causes

```
h[k] = []
```

to be executed. For example, if

```
h #=> { 2=>[0] }
```

then

```
h[11] << 1
```

causes

```
h[11] = []
```

to be executed (since `h` does not have a key `11`), after which

```
h[11] << 1
```

is executed, resulting in

```
h #=> { 2=>[0], 11=>[1] }
```

By contrast, if then

```
h[2] << 3
```

is executed we obtain

```
h #=> { 2=>[0,3], 11=>[1] }
```

without `h[2] = []` being executed because `h` already has a key `2`. See [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new).

---

Expressing block variables as

```
|(n,i),h|
```

is a form of [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition).